# How can I precisely control light feathering and distance?

Tags: node-editor, lighting, shader-nodes

For an i/o plugin, I need to supply values to these properties of the light format: `Falloff` (the distance at which the light intensity is 0) and `Falloff Exponent` (the feathering of the light, or softness of edges). It would need to behave like this:
[image]

Notice how at a falloff exponent of 0 the light is solid—there's no feathering. I've already experimented with the light falloff node and was never able to come close to this result. So far, it has seemed I can't even control the "feathering" of the light (other than the radius property). Is what I am trying to accomplish even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The radius (as you said) and Blend Options are a way to manage something close

[image]

Comment: I'm aware of those properties but they don't work in this case as I need more fine control if possible

Comment: @Emir: your gif is really hard to recognize...